# Is there a way to * out the selection made from a wicket select list?

Tags: java, html, wicket

Is there a way to * out the selection made from a wicket select list similar to how you * out the text in a password field?

(im using java, HTML and wicket in my project)

Answer (score 2):

You could use wicket-extensions's `AjaxEditableChoiceLabel`.

```
 List<String> options = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
 form.add(new AjaxEditableChoiceLabel<>("choice", options) {
    @Override protected WebComponent newLabel(final MarkupContainer parent, final String componentId, final IModel<T> model) {
      return new Label(componentId, "********");
    }
 });
```

See a demo at https://examples9x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/editable-label

By default it uses a `Label` to show the `view` mode, but you could use any custom Component that shows a mask by overriding its `protected WebComponent newLabel(final MarkupContainer parent, final String componentId, final IModel<T> model)` method.

See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/5897251e6fdc2d3d51bbb607dd908dd2f72e833a/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/ajax/builtin/EditableLabelPage.java for sample code.